# Getting access to a Polymer method inside a function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polymer, dom-events

I use the Polymer Google Map element and I've faced with a problem while adding an event listener to the map.

```
    * blah blah blah *
    ready: function () {
        this.map.addEventListener('google-map-rightclick', this._rightClickOnMap);
    },
    test: function () {
        console.log(1);
    },
    _rightClickOnMap: function (event) {
        this.test();
    }
    * blah blah blah *
```

I've tried to bind this to the listener but JS throw me the error

```
this.map.addEventListener('google-map-rightclick', this._rightClickOnMap).bind(this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call bind on the function and not on the event listener.

```
this.map.addEventListener('google-map-rightclick', this._rightClickOnMap.bind(this));
```