# Calling a Polymer function inside a callback gives 'TypeError .. is not a function'

Tags: javascript, google-api, polymer

When using the Google API in Polymer with `<google-signin>` and `<google-signin-aware>`, I can retrieve calendar data, and it logs to the console, but passing this data to another Polymer function (outside of the callback) does not work.

I've tried applying tips from the answer as shown here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24716257/5779929 to pass this by using `.bind(this)` directly on the function:

```
handleResponse: function (response) {
    console.log('got response: ', response);
    this.calendar = response;
},

listUpcomingEvents: function () {
    var queryBody = { 'showDeleted': false };

    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list(queryBody);

    request.execute(function (resp) {
        console.log(resp);
        this.handleResponse(resp);
    }.bind(this));
},
```

The call to `this.handleResponse` in the above snippet gives:

> "Uncaught TypeError: this.handleResponse is not a function"

I've tried to write it like this:
`request.execute(this.handleResponse.bind(this));`
 as shown here: [Getting access to a Polymer method inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37036626/getting-access-to-a-polymer-method-inside-a-function),
but that gives:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined"

Comment: How, or where from is `listUpcomingEvents` being called?

Comment: Bind your "listUpcomingEvents" function with its host object . `var someObj = { listUpcomingEvents: function(){} }; someObj.listUpcomingEvents = someObj.listUpcomingEvents.bind(someObj);`

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer it's triggered by an event on-google-signin-aware-success, as shown here: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-signin?active=google-signin-aware, with a few parameters allows the use of the google-api: gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', this.listUpcomingEvents);
which works as far as I can tell

Comment: @RobertvanAlphen That call is also where you need to bind: `gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', this.listUpcomingEvents.bind(this));`

Comment: @tony19 that works! This has been bugging me for days! I'm so grateful! I'm new to asking questions here, can I mark your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discovered in comments, you were passing your Polymer object's function without binding the context. When the callback was invoked, the context was not your Polymer object, so `handleResponse` was not found.

This is resolved by binding the context with `.bind(this)` when you pass the function:

```
_onApiReady: function() {
  ...
  gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', this.listUpcomingEvents.bind(this));
}
```